# Sponsored Tags Pages Missing Links

Tags: discussion, feature-request, status-completed, tags-page

Take a look at the following tag paages:

[**`[Visual-Studio]`**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/visual-studio)
[image: image of Visual Studio tag page]

[**`[Eclipse]`**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/eclipse)
[image: image of Eclipse tag page]

The Visual Studio page is missing the row of links that looks like this:

> about the eclipse tag | faq | stats | hot answers | new answers | synonyms

This makes it much more difficult to find this information.  I think this row of links should be placed under the sponsored links.

*(I see the 'about »' link next to the tag, but that is much less discoverable than the row of links.)*

Comment: I'd be tempted to re-tag this as a bug.

Comment: @MPel, well, as a bug, it will get [status-bydesign], as a feature request it has life.

Comment: @jjnguy: Not a bad idea...

Comment: @jjnguy, but at the same time it proves that there's something wrong if one has to *play the system* that way. It's a design bug, that's it.

Comment: @Mpell, I think the system works fairly well.  The team just has different priorities from its users sometimes.

Comment: [feature-request] --> [status-declined]

Comment: @Ivo, why do you say that?

Comment: Just because off your false sense of security by using the feature-request tag ;-)

Comment: @Ivo, ah.  Yeah.  Every tag has its risks I suppose.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Links are no longer missing, we added them for sponsored tags as well.