# Can we add the "linkbar" to the bottom of all sponsored tags?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Sponsored Tags Pages Missing Links](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/62560/sponsored-tags-pages-missing-links)

Currently sponsored tags have neither the tag wiki "excerpt" nor the "linkbar" beneath that.  At the very least sponsored tags should have the links at the bottom of the sponsorship tag area like any other tag.  Otherwise it is breaking the user experience of expected things on the tag page.

"about the android tag | faq | top users | hot answers | new answers | synonyms "

[My other related question to this that sparked this question.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/69927/adding-a-link-to-android-se-on-the-android-tag-wiki)

Comment: Awk... sorry. I guess I missed that one. Well, I s'pose you have a feature request you can vote up, now!